# Comparing value of same key between multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to create a function that will take an arbitrary number of dictionaries as arguments and return the dictionary with the lowest value for the `'qty'` key.  All dictionaries have the same number of items and are formatted as follows:

```
dictA = {'qty':1000, 'color':'red'}
dictB = {'qty':3000, 'color':'red'}
dictC = {'qty':5000, 'color':'red'}
...
```

I know how to return the min value :

```
def minQty(*args):
    return min([i['qty'] for i in args])
```

But I am having trouble grasping how to return the dictionary itself in that situation.

The desired output would look like this:

```
>>> minQty(dictA, dictB, dictC)
dictA
```

Comment: Do you have to worry about the case where there might be multiple dictionaries with the same value of `qty`?  (PS: you mean "arbitrary", not "infinite".)

Comment: @DSM  Didn't think about that possibility but yes, it could be problematic.  In that case I would compare the two dict with another key.  I didn't specify in this example but the dict also have a unique timestamp for the time their were created.  I would return the dict with the oldest timestamp.

P.S. Thanks for pointing it out,  just changed to arbitrary instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `key` argument to the `min()` function; it lets you pick one of the dictionaries based on the return value of the `key` (called per dictionary):

```
def minQty(*args):
    return min(args, key=lambda d: d['qty'])
```

Instead of a lambda, you can also use the [`operator.itemgetter()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) to create a callable for the key:

```
from operator import itemgetter

def minQty(*args):
    return min(args, key=itemgetter('qty'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> dictA = {'qty':1000, 'color':'red'}
>>> dictB = {'qty':3000, 'color':'red'}
>>> dictC = {'qty':5000, 'color':'red'}
>>> def minQty(*args):
...     return min(args, key=itemgetter('qty'))
... 
>>> minQty(dictA, dictB, dictC)
{'color': 'red', 'qty': 1000}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `operator.itemgetter` as the key to min to find the dict with the lowest value for `qty`:

```
dictA = {'qty':1000, 'color':'red'}
dictB = {'qty':3000, 'color':'red'}
dictC = {'qty':5000, 'color':'red'}

from operator import itemgetter

def minQty(*args):
    return min(args,key=itemgetter("qty"))

print(minQty(dictA, dictB, dictC))
```

If you potentially have dicts that may not have the key then you should use `dict.get` with a default value of `float(inf)`:

```
def minQty(*args):
    return min(args, key=lambda x:x.get('qty',float("inf")))
```